# Double vs Float80 speed in Swift

Tags: swift, floating-point, x86, x86-64, x87

I've heard that the x87 FPU works with 80-bit floats, so even if I want to calculate using 64-bit numbers, it would calculate it with 80-bit and then convert it. But which is fastest in Swift on **x86-64**, `Double` or `Float80` (when calculating arithmetic)?

Comment: I also can imagine that the actual speed won't be affected by the language (Swift vs C vs any other language) because it's essentially the instruction speed.

Comment: But if you ignore the language, is 80-bit floats faster on x86-64?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it's true that the x87 FPU operates internally at 80-bit "extended" precision (at least, by default; this is customizable, and in fact 32-bit builds following the macOS ABI set 64-bit internal precision), **binaries targeting x86-64 no longer use x87 FPU instructions**. All x86 chips that implement the 64-bit long mode extension also support SSE2 (in fact, this was required by the AMD64 specification), so a 64-bit binary can always assume SSE2 support. As such, this is what is used to implement floating-point operations, because it's much more efficient and easier to optimize around for a compiler.

Even 32-bit builds in the modern era assume SSE2 as a minimum, and *certainly* on the Macintosh platform, since SSE2 was introduced with the Pentium 4, which predated the Macintosh platform's switch to Intel x86 chips. All x86 chips ever used in an Apple machine support SSE2.

So no, you aren't going to see any performance improvement by using an 80-bit extended precision type. You weren't going to see any performance improvement from x87 instructions, even if they were generated by the compiler. And you *certainly* aren't going to see any performance improvement on x86-64, because SSE2 supports a maximum of 64-bit precision in hardware. Any 80-bit precision operations are going to have to be implemented in software, or force a smart compiler to emit x87 instructions, which means you don't benefit from any of the nice features and tangible performance improvements of SSE2.

Comment: Delphi is one of the languages that, on Win32, use a float80 type (called Extended, in Delphi) by default. It is not faster than float64 (called Double). But, due to its size (10 bytes), it can cause a few alignment problems (e.g. when stored in arrays), making it slower than Double (float64).

Comment: This answer confuses x87 FPU and x87 instructions throughout. The x86-64 ISA **does include** the historical “x87” instructions. There is no “fallback to the x87 FPU” when executing one of these instructions, because there is no such thing as a dedicated part of a modern x86-64 CPU dedicated exclusively to historical x87 instructions that could be called a “x87 FPU”. And the idea that this might be implemented in software is ridiculous, since the x86-64 ISA includes instructions for extended-double computations.

Comment: Haswell, for instance, executes FMUL on port 0, the very same port that executes some SSE2 FP multiplication instructions, and also integer arithmetics. Reference: page 140 on the current version of http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf

Comment: Of course it includes them, I didn't suggest otherwise. I'm using x87 FPU conceptually here, referring to the instructions. I suppose that wording could be confusing. I used the term "fall back" because the compiler does not ordinarily generate x87 instructions and they are considered obsolete. How the hardware actually implements those instructions is not relevant, or at least I didn't think it was relevant in this case. You might say it is "ridiculous" to see extended-double computations implemented in software on x86-64, but it absolutely *happens*.

Answer (score 5):

`Double` will almost always[1] be at least as fast on `Float80` on modern Intel processors, in almost any language. There are some situations in which it will be significantly faster:

- `Double` uses less memory; it's possible for an algorithm's working set to fit in cache when using `Double`, but fail to fit when using `Float80`, causing significant performance hazards.
- `Double` can take advantage for FMA instructions (exposed in Swift as `.add[ing]Product(x,y)` and the `fma()` free function), which effectively doubles the attainable floating-point throughput on recent cores.
- `Double` can be auto-vectorized by the compiler. There are no vector instructions on `Float80`. When possible, this can give you up to a 4x speedup.
- Math functions like `sin`, `cos`, `pow`, etc. are faster on `Double` than they are on `Float80`.

There are some other reasons to use `Double`: it's portable to non-x86 hardware, whereas `Float80` is not, and interoperability with C interfaces is easier with `Double` than it is with `Float80`. You should only use `Float80` when necessary, and default to using `Double` otherwise.

[1] There are a few niche cases where `Float80` can be faster--if an algorithm repeatedly underflows in `Double`, but remains in normal range in `Float80`, for example. These are rare, and usually not worth worrying about; more commonly your algorithm will also underflow in `Float80`, just do it a few iterations later.

Comment: `fld` and `fst` for 80-bit operands are slower than for 32 or 64-bit.  Even on older x86 CPUs like Nehalem, `fld m80` is 4 uops instead of 1, and half the throughput of `fld m32/m64`.  On Skylake, `fld m80` is still 4 uops with 1 per 2c throughput, but `fld m64` is one per 0.5c.  `fst(p) m80` throughput is even worse: 1 per 5 cycles.  (load and store are each implemented as two separate load or store uops, plus some ALU)

Comment: Vectorizing with FMA could give an 8x increase in FLOPS for `double`.  As for other speedups, `vcmppd` can also be a lot more efficient than x87 comparisons...

Comment: @PeterCordes: yeah, there's a bunch of other factors that I'm glossing over (2/4x as many registers, fast min/max, etc), just trying to mention the biggest factors, not an exhaustive list.

Comment: Right of course.  I meant to say I knew you were keeping it simple, but accidentally left that out.  I thought it was useful to point out that 80-bit is slower than `double` even if both are done with x87, even if cache misses aren't a factor.  It's clearly a 2nd-class citizen.